# Will an android app release to play market lock update to previous app version?

Tags: android, google-play, release

Suppose there is 3 versions of the Android App.

Version 1.0 — the initial release

Version 1.1 — released on 100% but still exist users with 1.0

Version 1.2 — released on 1%

I released new version of the Android App (Version 1.2) on 1%

It's possible for users with old versions (Version 1.0) to get a previous version of the app (Version 1.1) with an autoupdate or an autoupdate will be blocked until full release of 1.2 ?

Answer (score 0):

The user will always get the most recent version that is compatible with their phone.

for example, if your apps min sdk is android 7 and any device that is android 7 and up will be able to download it.

If you make an update to your app and change the min SDK to android 9 and up then the users who are android 7 will only get the updates to right before you changed the min sdk version.

Version 1.0 (min sdk 24) - user downloads app

Version 1.1 (min sdk 24) - user gets this update

Version 1.2 (min sdk 29) - user does not get this update.

If the user does not have auto update on and only has the initial version they downloaded (ie 1.0) then the next time they go to manually update they will get the latest version 1.2 (not taking into account min sdk version of the device)

Comment: An important result of this advice-  any changes you make to data formats (in either files or db schemas) need to be either backwards compatible with, or need to be able to convert from any version the user might be upgrading from.  So if you changed db schemas in v1.1 and v1.2, v1.2 needs to be able to convert the data from a 1.1 or 1.0 version, or be willing to delete the old data and start fresh.